# MS Dynamics SDK returning "Cannot access a disposed object"

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

In our .NET project we are using the Dynamics SDK (version 8.2.0.2) to access Dynamics 365 from our website. We used the CrmSvcUtil tool to generate the early bound classes to work with.

In our dependency resolver we are injecting the connection to Dynamics whenever a request for the IOrganizationService is requested, as follows:

```
container.For<IOrganizationService>()
            .Singleton()
            .Use(ctx => new OrganizationService(new CrmConnection("CrmConnection")));
```

In our class that deals with communicating with Dynamics, our constructor is created to have an instance of the IOrganizationService injected into it, as follows:

```
        private readonly IOrganizationService _organizationService;
    private readonly ILog _logger;

    public CrmAccount(IOrganizationService organizationService, ILog logger)
    {
        _organizationService = organizationService;
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

Within this class, we have various methods. One for example updates a users Contact record. I've made the method small for the purpose of this post i.e. im not showing all of the properties we're updating, but the structure of the code remains the same:

```
        public Guid? SetProfile(string username)
    {
        using (var xrm = new XrmServiceContext(_organizationService))
        {
            //check whether account already exists
            var crmProfile = GetContact(xrm, username);

            if (crmProfile == null)
            {
                //create new account if required
                crmProfile = new Contact
                {
                    EMailAddress1 = profile.Username,
                };
                xrm.AddObject(crmProfile);
            }
            else
            {
                //update existing account
                crmProfile.EMailAddress1 = profile.Username;
                xrm.UpdateObject(crmProfile);
            }

            var response = xrm.SaveChanges();

            if (!response.HasError) return crmProfile.Id;
            foreach (var result in response)
            {
                if (result.Error != null)
                {
                    _logger.ErrorFormat("Failed to create Profile record for Profile with guid {0}:/r/n{1}", crmProfile.Id, result.Error.Message);
                }
            }

            return crmProfile.Id;
        }
    }
```

The problem that we are seeing is that every so often, when multiple users try to call this method at the same time we receive an error message "Cannot access a disposed object" when the xrm.SaveChanges() method is called.

I realise that wrappign our code in a using statement means that when the final brace is reached the object is disposed off, but I also assumed that each call to this method would create it's own instance of the OrganizationService and hence the object would never be disposed off within the scope of a single users call to this method.

Am I missing something obvious here? It is afterall how Microsoft recommend carrying out transactions against Dynamics.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Kind regards,

dotdev

Answer (score 0):

Your IoC container provides an `IOrganizationService` object as a **singleton**. This means that every request actually consumes one and the same instance. However, an `OrganizationService` instance cannot be used by multiple threads at the same time.

For a web service using Dynamics CRM as a back end store a good option could be to design a pool of `IOrganizationService` instances. Each request gets an instance from the pool, performs its task and finally returns the `IOrganizationService` instance to the pool, where it will be available for reuse.

Comment: Hi Henk. Thanks for your response. Do you know of any good code examples to acomplish this? Could the same be acheived by NOT using a singleton?

Comment: I don't know which IOC framework you are using; maybe it has some of the functionality available already. You could start with replacing the singleton construction by a provider that provides IOrganizationService instances as per request.

Comment: Im using  StructureMap. I think the problem with "Per Request" is that the call to the Dynamics web service will need to authenticate each and every time. Would an alternative just be to use container.For<IOrganizationService>().LifecycleIs(new ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle()).Use(ctx => new OrganizationService(new CrmConnection("CrmConnection"))); ? Unless I misunderstand, this will create a new OrganisationService for each thread...

Comment: I do not have experience with StructureMap, but your suggestion sounds like a better approach.

Comment: @dotdev did you ever get this resolved? I'm looking to solve the same problem.