# MS Dynamics throwing object disposed error after first authentication token expires

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics, dotnet-httpclient

I'm having a very similar issue to [MS Dynamics SDK returning "Cannot access a disposed object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416129/ms-dynamics-sdk-returning-cannot-access-a-disposed-object/70118834#70118834) using the .NET dynamics SDK, but with a simpler system not using the IOrg service. This works the first times until the token expires, then if this is run a any time **after the original token expires**, it fails on the **AcquireTokenAsync** (the var authresult line) with a `cannot access disposed object` error hitting the catch.

To make it clear this function is a MS Function, I do not have access to the source for this function, the objects being passed do not appear disposed and the authContext is not itself disposed.

I have verified that none of the objects here are disposed. I have looked at the internal objects of each one as well (as far as I could) and none of those are null/disposed that I could see.

```
internal static void Init(string _clientId, ISecureClientSecret _secret, string _authority = null, string _resourceUrl = null)
    {
        clientId = _clientId;
        clientSecret = _secret;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_authority))
        {
            authority = _authority;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_resourceUrl))
        {
            resourceUrl = _resourceUrl;
        }

        initClient();
    }

private static void initClient() 
{
            try
            {
                _client = new HttpClient();
                var authContext         = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
                var clientCredentials   = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret); //Secret is of type ISecureClientSecret set in init.
                var authResult          = DynamicsLeadWorkflow.AsyncUtil.RunSync<AuthenticationResult>(() => authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUrl, clientCredentials));

                if(authResult == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authResult.AccessToken))
                {
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Couldn't acquire the token from Dynamics");
                }

                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                _client.BaseAddress                         = new Uri(resourceUrl);
                clientCreated                               = DateTime.Now;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ERROR(ex);
            }
}
```

Some notes:
initClient() is hit if the token expiry has passed (it is also run prior to this in other ways) - the ONYL time it fails is after the first token expires.

ClientSecret is an ISecureClientSecret set when the package initialises. (I am now wondering if this is going out of scope and being disposed of).

authority is the login authority url.

clientCreated is to be ignored

The runsync funcs:

```
public static class AsyncUtil
    {
        private static readonly TaskFactory _taskFactory = new
        TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.None,
            TaskScheduler.Default);

        public static void RunSync(Func<Task> task)
            => _taskFactory
                .StartNew(task)
                .Unwrap()
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();

        public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> task)
        {
            return _taskFactory
                .StartNew(task)
                .Unwrap()
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Lots of the prpoperties are not defined and not assigned. You have to post the full real code if  you need  some help.

Comment: All properties that are missing are not required, if you see the only missing properties are the actual creds and endpoint.

There are some extraneous bits (such as the created time) and the bits where it is adding the token to the header of the httpclient. But these are not where the issue is occurring and only included from a sense of completeness

Comment: If you are so sure , then it is inside of AcquireTokenAsync. You could post it too

Comment: AcquireTokenAsync is a MS function. This is the issue. I will test and make sure the securestring isn't going out of scope today, but if that isn't then all code on my side is fine.
If you read the linked issue, you will see that in that case it was because the ms func was pushing the list of orgs out of scope in another thread. Apparently this was deliberate and just not documented by MS in their docs.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling async function using await inside of sync method. You have to call a method as sync

```
var authResult  = authContext
                  .AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUrl, clientCredentials).Result;
```

or change a method

```
private static async Task initClient()
```

Comment: Different error, some code has been removed. the async/await was tested both using result (unsafe and NOT recommended) as well as running synchronously.

As stated the method works the first time, and every time after that until the token expires.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the code for running async synchronously

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have a result, the use of a `ISecureClientSecret` will kill the `AcquireTokenAsync` function (or at least the extension provided by the dynamics SDK) if you are using the same ISecureClientSecret as you have used to previously connect.

Essentially what appears to happen is when the token expires, it disposes of the token object, as a string is immutable this doesn't affect a string passed in as the credentials, but if you pass the ISecureClientSecret and it is disposed, it kills the original version in your project (probably by reference).

**Solution:** use a string, or regenerate the ISecureClientSecret each time the token expires when you are reacquiring.